# ANT build.xml delete task of directory not working

Tags: java, xml, ant

i have an xml script for building a project out of this structure.

- src

  - src  files and package subdirs
- rsrc

  - build.xml

After building out of the src folder there is a build and lib folder created in rsrc

- src

  - src files and package subdirs
- rsrc

  - build

    - package subdirs
  - lib
  - build.xml

After everything worked, the build folder is filled with the .class files, in their package subdirs. In the lib folder the distribution .jar has it's place. Now to my problem i wrote this target named= "clean":

```
  <target name="clean"
        description="clean up" >
        <!-- Delete the ${build} directory tree -->
        <delete dir="${build}"/>
  </target>
```

Which should delete the build folder, its subfolders and contents.
The $ Build is defined as:

```
  <property name="build" location="build"/>
```

and the base directory as basedir="."

But nothing gets deleted, what am I doing wrong.

Best regards Stefan
(If you need additional information just ask please)

EDIT:
If i call it with "ant -v clean" the build file is deleted .. if i call with "ant" or "ant -verbose" its not.

Comment: Try running with `ant -v clean`.  That will show you exactly what Ant is trying to delete.  (And ignore the answers which recommend using ${basedir}/build—they apparently aren't aware that relative paths in Ant are already treated as relative to the basedir.)

Comment: if you post this as answer you are my top voted :) thank you so much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try running with `ant -v clean`.  That will show you exactly what Ant is trying to delete.  (And ignore the answers which recommend using ${basedir}/build—they apparently aren't aware that relative paths in Ant are already relative to the basedir.)

Comment: apparently it's only deleting the folder if ant -v clean is executed.. with ant -verbose or just ant the folder still exists

Comment: <project name="A12TEST" default="clean" basedir="."> there was the error.. instead of clean it was the procedure before. But your solution helped me to solve this

Answer (score 1):

Use property as below.

```
<property name="build" value="${basedir}/build"/>
```

Comment: problem still persists.. getting no error just BUILD Successfull and folder stays where created :(

Answer (score 1):

Try using ${basedir} instead. That will point to the parent directory of the buildfile. Also a common way to organize folders is to have your build.xml in the build folder and your output from building in build/output.

Comment: ${basedir} instead of..?

Comment: For referencing the current directory. So you would use "${basedir}/build" for the build directory in that case. But I saw in your other comment that it doesn't work. Maybe it's a permission problem, try running Ant as an administrator task. Also, make sure that the file isn't locked by some other Ant task.

Comment: Also tried as administrator task.. Is there a way to observer the xml script in a way. Tried ant -verbose but no error or warning, but also no mention of the delete procedure

Comment: None that I know of. Might be a process hanging, try rebooting if nothing else works. Also, are you using this file in another task? Or is this all of your build.xml file.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you forgot to call the target "clean"?

Try executing your ant with -v flag so we can see the output ant generates in order to see if the target is executed.

To see if the directory is correct, you can add `<echo message="${build}"/>` (http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/echo.html) in the target to verify the absolute path of the directory.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Stefan, have you tried to add the echo? With this echo task you can check if the target is being executed and which absolute path are you trying to delete.

Answer (score 0):

make `<target name="clean">` depend on **init**

```
<target name="init" depends="clean">
        code
    </target>
```